# Empty Column when creating using model and console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a `User` model as shown below:

```
#app/models/user.rb
```

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
         attr_accessor :name, :email

      email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

        validates :name, :presence=>true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
      validates :email, :presence=>true, :format => {:with => email_regex},
                :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
    end
```

Following is the migration code:

```
    class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :users do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.string :email

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
 
    end
```

After invoking migration, when I create Rows in the database, it does not add name and email field in the database.

Here is what I have tried:

`us1=User.create!(:name=>"Test1",:email=>"dev@d.com")
        (0.0ms)  begin transaction
        User Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('dev@d.com') LIMIT 1
       SQL (0.0ms)INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-04-28 14:30:18.874632"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-28 14:30:18.874632"]]
      (109.2ms)  commit transaction
     => #<User id: 1, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: "2015-04-28 14:30:18", updated_at: "2015-04-28 14:30:18">`

Ruby and Rails version:
Rails: 4.2.1
Ruby: 2.0.0p643

What is wrong with Model and migration or my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line

```
attr_accessor :name, :email
```

Since you've added these columns in the migration already. (Rails will generate appropriate methods from the database schema for you automatically.)

Comment: Thanks. It means this line is hindering with methods generated.